# migrate to equinox P2 for update site - Juno

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rcp, update-site

I am trying to migrate an update-site plugin for my product from eclipse equinox to Juno , when I create a new plugin project and copy paste all the src files and change the META-INF as per the previous proj, I get lots of compilation errors.Reason being org.eclipse.update.core removed from Juno.So i have to migrate this existing project to equinox P2.But couldnt find a way to do so as i am completely new to RCP/plugin development.Can someone help me with some pointers. I get "cannot be resolved in to a type error for the following"

UpdateSearchRequest
ContentEntryModel
IFeature
IURLEntry
ICategory
Messages
IFeatureReference
IUpdateModelChangedListener
ISite
IIncludedFeatureReference

etc...

Answer (score 0):

http://plosquare.blogspot.com/2009/05/migrating-eclipse-update-sites-to-p2.html

Perhaps the above might help.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like the following to get started:

1. Open the Plug-ins View via Window->Show View->Other...->Plug-in Development->Plug-ins
2. Select all the plug-ins, right click and select "Add to Java Search..."
3. Ctrl-O and type one of the class files you listed above

This will allow you to open editors for those classes to see if they're still around.  From the editor, you can figure out what Plug-in they're in and start fixing your Plug-in Dependencies in the Manifest Editor.  Then you can start fixing the imports in your source either by hand or via Organize imports.